Python: Issue with installing Zebra Scanner package on Debian
i am trying to install this on a debian system (Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm))
the newest version of this zebra scanner project is from Aug 2021
i have issues with the installation of the zebra-scanner as well as issues with finding packages
i am still somewhat new so it might have been something obvious i have missed
1.
i am currently at the step of pip3 install . inside my virtual enviroment
i am getting this error message: error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
this is the whole message from the console:
(vzebra) debuser@debianIntrasrv:~/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5$ pip3 install .
Processing /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: zebra-scanner
  Building wheel for zebra-scanner (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/vzebra/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:534: UserWarning: Normalizing 'v0.2.5' to '0.2.5'
        warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'zebra_scanner' extension
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/zebra-scanner -I/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/vzebra/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src -I/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/vzebra/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.o -Wno-deprecated -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden
      In file included from /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.cpp:1:
      /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.h:13:10: fatal error: CsIEventListenerXml.h: No such file or directory
         13 | #include "CsIEventListenerXml.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for zebra-scanner
  Running setup.py clean for zebra-scanner
Failed to build zebra-scanner
Installing collected packages: zebra-scanner
  Running setup.py install for zebra-scanner ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for zebra-scanner did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/vzebra/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:534: UserWarning: Normalizing 'v0.2.5' to '0.2.5'
        warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
      running install
      /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/vzebra/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'zebra_scanner' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/home
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/home/debuser
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/home/debuser/ZebraScanner
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/zebra-scanner -I/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/vzebra/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src -I/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/vzebra/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.o -Wno-deprecated -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden
      In file included from /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.cpp:1:
      /home/debuser/ZebraScanner/zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.h:13:10: fatal error: CsIEventListenerXml.h: No such file or directory
         13 | #include "CsIEventListenerXml.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> zebra-scanner

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.


i have tried to find similar problems. i might have missed some solutions.
2.
i also have an issue that my system cannot find certain packages
E: Unable to locate package python-opengl
E: Unable to locate package python-pil
E: Unable to locate package python-pyrex
E: Unable to locate package python-pyside.qtopengl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python-pyside.qtopengl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python-pyside.qtopengl'
E: Unable to locate package idle-python2.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'idle-python2.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'idle-python2.7'
E: Unable to locate package qt4-dev-tools
E: Unable to locate package qt4-designer
E: Package 'libqtgui4' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libqtcore4' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-xml
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-test
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-script
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-network
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-dbus
E: Unable to locate package python-qt4
E: Unable to locate package python-qt4-gl
E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate

this is my very first question here since it is specific to the zebra installation. but if it is something obvious i do hope to learn something from anyone that answers
Thank you for your time
Edit:
the issue seems to be with the inclusion of files within the zebra package:
zebra-scanner-0.2.5/src/BoostPythonCoreScanner.h
it tries to
#include "CsIEventListenerXml.h"
#include "CsUserDefs.h"
#include "CsBarcodeTypes.h"
#include "Cslibcorescanner_xml.h"

...


#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

..


#include <Python.h>

but it seems like it cannot get these. I also cannot find these files anywhere localy within the project. should these files have been with the project or did i miss something?
